# Swift. How to copy string?

Tags: string, swift

how can i parse strings in swift? i have html page. I need copy parameter. for example:

dxxxxxxxx/js/scroll_page.js?**id=1234567890123456**

I must copy a parameter id. How to do it in swift?

PS: sorry for my english. i'm Russian.

```
*@IBAction func StartClick(sender: UIButton) {

            let url = NSURL(string: "http://spaces.ru/")
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
            let html = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let sid: String = html.substringToIndex(992)
            println(sid)

        }
        task.resume()*
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the NSRegularExpression class.

Comment: how to do it? please, answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit old of a question, but for others try this:

```
var id = "dxxxxxxxx/js/scroll_page.js?id=1234567890123456"

var result = id.componentsSeparatedByString("id=")
result[1]
```

*result* is an array and the id is in the second element.